# Merge results of two queries into one result

Tags: t-sql, select

I have two queries. First one returns then number of Incidents created and closed in the same day for a date range:

```
SELECT Count(*) [# Incidents Closed First Day], CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rn_Create_Date, 101)  [Date]   
FROM dbo.Support_Incident
WHERE   --created and closed on same day. i.e closed first day     
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rn_Create_Date, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date_Closed, 101) AND 
    rn_Create_Date > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-01 00:00:00', 102) AND
    rn_Create_Date < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-30 00:00:00', 102)
GROUP  By CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rn_Create_Date, 101)
```

and I have another query that returns the total number of incidents created in the same date range grouped by Date:

```
SELECT Count(*) [Total Incidents Created], CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rn_Create_Date, 101)  [Date]
FROM dbo.Support_Incident
WHERE   
        rn_Create_Date > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-01 00:00:00', 102) 
    AND rn_Create_Date < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-30 00:00:00', 102)
GROUP  By  CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rn_Create_Date, 101)
```

What I really want is a single result set that combines these two queries so that each row would show the Number of incidents created in a day as well as the number that were created and closed the same day.

Is there a way to create a query that merges these two queries to provide a single result set?

Comment: yes - use these each as an inline view - and join them on date.

Comment: Thanks. That gets me a lot closer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UNION ALL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) clause to merge your results.

SQL UNION Syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```